# REACT - setState not working even when function its used is has already binded this in the constructor

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate

Below is the code I've used... there are some omitted code for other Components

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'deals': [], responsiveVisible: false, filterState: {
        productTypes:
        {
          broadband: true,
          tv: true,
          mobile: true
        }
      }
    };

    service.fetchDeals().then(deals => {
      this.setState({ 'deals': deals })
    })

    this.filterChanged = this.filterChanged.bind(this)
  }

  filterChanged(value) {

      this.setState({ filterState: value });

      console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
      //<BroadbandGrid deals={this.state.deals} />

    return (<div className="app">
      <SiteNav />
      <div className="deals-layout">
            <DealFilter filterChanged={this.filterChanged.bind(this)} filterState={this.state.filterState} />  
        <div className="deals-layout__grid" >
                <BroadbandGrid deals={this.filterDeals(this.state.filterState)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}`
```

As displayed i've done the binding for filterChanged where i will call setState
Yet when I reach setState, its says that filterState is undefined.  Let's also assume for a moment that value is a valid object.  (Since it is when I run my code)

Comment: how can filterState be undefined when its not even a variable or method ?

Comment: @Nizzy What error you are getting, if any ?

Comment: no need to `bind` again in the component: `filterChanged={this.filterChanged.bind(this)}`

Comment: Any reason why you're even using `.bind(this)` when es6 provides arrow functions that maintain the `this` context of the class? [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)

Comment: There is no need to use `.bind(this)` when you pass it to `DealFilter` as you have already bound it in your app's constructor.

Where exactly are you finding filterState undefined? Is it where you console log value? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: @klugjo - I am not sure.  I guess it means its an undefined variable.  When I debug in the browser dev tools and I hover over filterState, it has a popup saying that its undefined.

Comment: @DavinTryon - I see.  What are the main difference between the two?

Comment: @TPorter - It's the technique I'm used to and its more readable to me (bec I come from a c# which is a declarative language)

Comment: @Gibby - Which should I not bind again since I've already bounded it to the constructor?

Comment: @Madhavan.V - When I execute "this.setState({ filterState: value })" and hover over filterState, I get a popup saying its undefined and when I go to the console and look at this.state.filterState, it says its undefined

Comment: @Nizzy - I hadn't noticed David addressed this before me. There is no need for the bind in your render function
`<DealFilter filterChanged={this.filterChanged.bind(this)} ...` 
It's redundant as you've done this in the constructor.

Comment: @Gibby - done... but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: @Nizzy Nothing particularly stands out in what you posted. Are you seeing your console log print out multiple times every time you change a filter?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry i wasn't able to get back, thanks for your answers.  Its been sometime and I got involved in other projects, however I think I've already solved this as in a recent project with React Native.